# Why is the Vue.js input value not updating?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, event-bus, v-model

I have a Vue.js `text-input` component like the following:

```
<template>
    <input
        type="text"
        :id="name"
        :name="name"
        v-model="inputValue"
    >
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name', 'value'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                inputValue: this.value
            };
        },
        watch: {
            inputValue: function () {
                eventBus.$emit('inputChanged', {
                    type: 'text',
                    name: this.name,
                    value: this.inputValue
                });
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

And I am using that `text-input` in another component as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
        <text-input :name="row.name" :value="row.value">
        </text-input>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then, within the JS of the component using `text-input`, I have code like the following for removing `li` rows:

```
this.rows = this.rows.filter((row, i) => i !== idx);
```

The `filter` method is properly removing the row that has an index of `idx` from the `rows` array, and in the parent component, I can confirm that the row is indeed gone, however, if I have, for example, two rows, the first with a value of `1` and the second with a value of `2`, and then I delete the first row, even though the remaining row has a value of `2`, I am still seeing `1` in the text input.

Why? I don't understand why Vue.js is not updating the value of the text input, even though the value of `value` is clearly changing from `1` to `2`, and I can confirm that in the parent component.

Maybe I'm just not understanding how Vue.js and `v-model` work, but it seems like the value of the text input should update. Any advice/explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot mutate values between components like that.

Here is a sample snippet on how to properly pass values back and forth. You will need to use computed setter/getter. Added a button to change the value and reflect it back to the instance. It works for both directions.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" :id="name" v-model="inputValue" />
        <button @click="inputValue='value2'">click</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name', 'value'],
        computed: {
            inputValue: {
                get() {
                    return this.value;
                },
                set(val) {
                    this.$emit('updated', val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Notice that the "@updated" event updates back the local variable with the updated value:

```
    <text-input :name="row.name" :value="row.value" @updated="item=>row.value=item"></text-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code you are trying to listen to changes.. in v-model data..
// Your Vue components

```
<template>
    <input
        type="text"
        :id="name"
        :name="name"
        v-model="inputValue"
    >
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name', 'value'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                inputValue: ""
            };
        },
        
    };
</script>
```

If You really want to listen for changes..

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
        <text-input @keyup="_keyUp" :name="row.name" :value="row.value">
        </text-input>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in your component file

```
<template>...</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name', 'value'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                inputValue: ""
            };
        },
        methods : {
    _keyUp : () => {// handle events here}

    };
</script>
```

check here for events on input [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

To bind value from props..

get the props value, then assign it to 'inputValue' variable

it will reflect in tthe input element